# Invertible polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, inverse

Let a no-strictly monotone polynomial can I say that since is a continous function and it is not strictly monotone $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ then it is invertible from the Continuous Inverse Function Theorem? I think that it is equivalen to say that my function is not injective, it is right?

Comment: Assuming that the function is coninuous, then it is invertible if and only if it is either $\{$strictly increasing or strictly decreasing$\}$.  So, if it is continuous and is not either $\{$strictly increasing or strictly decreasing$\}$, then it is not invertible.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for the confirmation